# Where is jQuery.ajax defined in the jQuery source code?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find where `jQuery.ajax()` is defined in their source code. However, using `grep` does not seem to work.

Where is it?

Thank you.

```bash
> grep jQuery.ajax src/*
src/ajax.js:// Base "constructor" for jQuery.ajaxPrefilter and jQuery.ajaxTransport
src/ajax.js:        flatOptions = jQuery.ajaxSettings.flatOptions || {};
src/ajax.js:                params = jQuery.param( params, jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional );
src/ajax.js:        jQuery.ajax({
src/ajax.js:        return jQuery.ajax({
src/ajax.js:            ajaxExtend( target, jQuery.ajaxSettings );
src/ajax.js:            target = jQuery.ajaxSettings;
src/ajax.js:            s = jQuery.ajaxSetup( {}, options ),
src/ajax.js:            traditional = jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional;
src/ajax.js:// Want to move this to jQuery.ajax some day
src/manipulation.js:        jQuery.ajax({
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.ajax

That site is very useful for going through the jQuery source code.

---

Source in case above link goes dead:

```
function (url, options) {

    // If url is an object, simulate pre-1.5 signature
    if (typeof url === "object") {
        options = url;
        url = undefined;
    }

    // Force options to be an object
    options = options || {};

    var // Create the final options object
    s = jQuery.ajaxSetup({},
    options),
    // Callbacks context
    callbackContext = s.context || s,
    // Context for global events
    // It's the callbackContext if one was provided in the options
    // and if it's a DOM node or a jQuery collection
    globalEventContext = callbackContext !== s && (callbackContext.nodeType || callbackContext instanceof jQuery) ? jQuery(callbackContext) : jQuery.event,
    // Deferreds
    deferred = jQuery.Deferred(),
    completeDeferred = jQuery._Deferred(),
    // Status-dependent callbacks
    statusCode = s.statusCode || {},
    // ifModified key
    ifModifiedKey,
    // Headers (they are sent all at once)
    requestHeaders = {},
    requestHeadersNames = {},
    // Response headers
    responseHeadersString,
    responseHeaders,
    // transport
    transport,
    // timeout handle
    timeoutTimer,
    // Cross-domain detection vars
    parts,
    // The jqXHR state
    state = 0,
    // To know if global events are to be dispatched
    fireGlobals,
    // Loop variable
    i,
    // Fake xhr
    jqXHR = {

        readyState: 0,

        // Caches the header
        setRequestHeader: function (name, value) {
            if (!state) {
                var lname = name.toLowerCase();
                name = requestHeadersNames[lname] = requestHeadersNames[lname] || name;
                requestHeaders[name] = value;
            }
            return this;
        },

        // Raw string
        getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
            return state === 2 ? responseHeadersString : null;
        },

        // Builds headers hashtable if needed
        getResponseHeader: function (key) {
            var match;
            if (state === 2) {
                if (!responseHeaders) {
                    responseHeaders = {};
                    while ((match = rheaders.exec(responseHeadersString))) {
                        responseHeaders[match[1].toLowerCase()] = match[2];
                    }
                }
                match = responseHeaders[key.toLowerCase()];
            }
            return match === undefined ? null : match;
        },

        // Overrides response content-type header
        overrideMimeType: function (type) {
            if (!state) {
                s.mimeType = type;
            }
            return this;
        },

        // Cancel the request
        abort: function (statusText) {
            statusText = statusText || "abort";
            if (transport) {
                transport.abort(statusText);
            }
            done(0, statusText);
            return this;
        }
    };

    // Callback for when everything is done
    // It is defined here because jslint complains if it is declared
    // at the end of the function (which would be more logical and readable)


    function done(status, statusText, responses, headers) {

        // Called once
        if (state === 2) {
            return;
        }

        // State is "done" now
        state = 2;

        // Clear timeout if it exists
        if (timeoutTimer) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
        }

        // Dereference transport for early garbage collection
        // (no matter how long the jqXHR object will be used)
        transport = undefined;

        // Cache response headers
        responseHeadersString = headers || "";

        // Set readyState
        jqXHR.readyState = status ? 4 : 0;

        var isSuccess, success, error, response = responses ? ajaxHandleResponses(s, jqXHR, responses) : undefined,
        lastModified,
        etag;

        // If successful, handle type chaining
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304) {

            // Set the If-Modified-Since and/or If-None-Match header, if in ifModified mode.
            if (s.ifModified) {

                if ((lastModified = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"))) {
                    jQuery.lastModified[ifModifiedKey] = lastModified;
                }
                if ((etag = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Etag"))) {
                    jQuery.etag[ifModifiedKey] = etag;
                }
            }

            // If not modified
            if (status === 304) {

                statusText = "notmodified";
                isSuccess = true;

                // If we have data
            } else {

                try {
                    success = ajaxConvert(s, response);
                    statusText = "success";
                    isSuccess = true;
                } catch(e) {
                    // We have a parsererror
                    statusText = "parsererror";
                    error = e;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // We extract error from statusText
            // then normalize statusText and status for non-aborts
            error = statusText;
            if (!statusText || status) {
                statusText = "error";
                if (status < 0) {
                    status = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Set data for the fake xhr object
        jqXHR.status = status;
        jqXHR.statusText = statusText;

        // Success/Error
        if (isSuccess) {
            deferred.resolveWith(callbackContext, [success, statusText, jqXHR]);
        } else {
            deferred.rejectWith(callbackContext, [jqXHR, statusText, error]);
        }

        // Status-dependent callbacks
        jqXHR.statusCode(statusCode);
        statusCode = undefined;

        if (fireGlobals) {
            globalEventContext.trigger("ajax" + (isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error"), [jqXHR, s, isSuccess ? success : error]);
        }

        // Complete
        completeDeferred.resolveWith(callbackContext, [jqXHR, statusText]);

        if (fireGlobals) {
            globalEventContext.trigger("ajaxComplete", [jqXHR, s]);
            // Handle the global AJAX counter
            if (! (--jQuery.active)) {
                jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
            }
        }
    }

    // Attach deferreds
    deferred.promise(jqXHR);
    jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done;
    jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;
    jqXHR.complete = completeDeferred.done;

    // Status-dependent callbacks
    jqXHR.statusCode = function (map) {
        if (map) {
            var tmp;
            if (state < 2) {
                for (tmp in map) {
                    statusCode[tmp] = [statusCode[tmp], map[tmp]];
                }
            } else {
                tmp = map[jqXHR.status];
                jqXHR.then(tmp, tmp);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    // Remove hash character (#7531: and string promotion)
    // Add protocol if not provided (#5866: IE7 issue with protocol-less urls)
    // We also use the url parameter if available
    s.url = ((url || s.url) + "").replace(rhash, "").replace(rprotocol, ajaxLocParts[1] + "//");

    // Extract dataTypes list
    s.dataTypes = jQuery.trim(s.dataType || "*").toLowerCase().split(rspacesAjax);

    // Determine if a cross-domain request is in order
    if (s.crossDomain == null) {
        parts = rurl.exec(s.url.toLowerCase());
        s.crossDomain = !!(parts && (parts[1] != ajaxLocParts[1] || parts[2] != ajaxLocParts[2] || (parts[3] || (parts[1] === "http:" ? 80 : 443)) != (ajaxLocParts[3] || (ajaxLocParts[1] === "http:" ? 80 : 443))));
    }

    // Convert data if not already a string
    if (s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string") {
        s.data = jQuery.param(s.data, s.traditional);
    }

    // Apply prefilters
    inspectPrefiltersOrTransports(prefilters, s, options, jqXHR);

    // If request was aborted inside a prefiler, stop there
    if (state === 2) {
        return false;
    }

    // We can fire global events as of now if asked to
    fireGlobals = s.global;

    // Uppercase the type
    s.type = s.type.toUpperCase();

    // Determine if request has content
    s.hasContent = !rnoContent.test(s.type);

    // Watch for a new set of requests
    if (fireGlobals && jQuery.active++===0) {
        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStart");
    }

    // More options handling for requests with no content
    if (!s.hasContent) {

        // If data is available, append data to url
        if (s.data) {
            s.url += (rquery.test(s.url) ? "&" : "?") + s.data;
        }

        // Get ifModifiedKey before adding the anti-cache parameter
        ifModifiedKey = s.url;

        // Add anti-cache in url if needed
        if (s.cache === false) {

            var ts = jQuery.now(),
            // try replacing _= if it is there
            ret = s.url.replace(rts, "$1_=" + ts);

            // if nothing was replaced, add timestamp to the end
            s.url = ret + ((ret === s.url) ? (rquery.test(s.url) ? "&" : "?") + "_=" + ts : "");
        }
    }

    // Set the correct header, if data is being sent
    if (s.data && s.hasContent && s.contentType !== false || options.contentType) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", s.contentType);
    }

    // Set the If-Modified-Since and/or If-None-Match header, if in ifModified mode.
    if (s.ifModified) {
        ifModifiedKey = ifModifiedKey || s.url;
        if (jQuery.lastModified[ifModifiedKey]) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", jQuery.lastModified[ifModifiedKey]);
        }
        if (jQuery.etag[ifModifiedKey]) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", jQuery.etag[ifModifiedKey]);
        }
    }

    // Set the Accepts header for the server, depending on the dataType
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", s.dataTypes[0] && s.accepts[s.dataTypes[0]] ? s.accepts[s.dataTypes[0]] + (s.dataTypes[0] !== "*" ? ", */*; q=0.01" : "") : s.accepts["*"]);

    // Check for headers option
    for (i in s.headers) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader(i, s.headers[i]);
    }

    // Allow custom headers/mimetypes and early abort
    if (s.beforeSend && (s.beforeSend.call(callbackContext, jqXHR, s) === false || state === 2)) {
        // Abort if not done already
        jqXHR.abort();
        return false;

    }

    // Install callbacks on deferreds
    for (i in {
        success: 1,
        error: 1,
        complete: 1
    }) {
        jqXHR[i](s[i]);
    }

    // Get transport
    transport = inspectPrefiltersOrTransports(transports, s, options, jqXHR);

    // If no transport, we auto-abort
    if (!transport) {
        done(-1, "No Transport");
    } else {
        jqXHR.readyState = 1;
        // Send global event
        if (fireGlobals) {
            globalEventContext.trigger("ajaxSend", [jqXHR, s]);
        }
        // Timeout
        if (s.async && s.timeout > 0) {
            timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                jqXHR.abort("timeout");
            },
            s.timeout);
        }

        try {
            state = 1;
            transport.send(requestHeaders, done);
        } catch(e) {
            // Propagate exception as error if not done
            if (status < 2) {
                done(-1, e);
                // Simply rethrow otherwise
            } else {
                jQuery.error(e);
            }
        }
    }

    return jqXHR;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[In `ajax.js`, line 388](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.7.0/src/ajax.js#L388-L834):

```
jQuery.extend({
    //...
    ajax: function( url, options ) {
```