# AJAX done() executed when finished all of request staff

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request to let the user delete some data from the list. When the ajax done I call another ajax request so the list updated with new the list of data. AJAX request to delete data:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: urlRequest,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log('removed');                          
    // the follow function call an ajax with get request so as the list will be updated with the new one
    ajaxRequestToGetNewData();    
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('fail');
})
```

The delete request above has a lot of information to delete, some text and some images and I am worried if `ajaxRequestToGetNewData()` will be called before the server finishes all of this stuff.

**My question**: Is the `.done()` method safe for the above situation? If not, is there any other jQuery method that will be executed only if the request finishes all of its stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely safe.

The `done()` handler will not be called until the promise returned by the `$.ajax` method has been resolved, which will only happen after the server has finished processing and returns a `200 OK` response. If any other response is received then the `fail()` handler will execute instead.

In both cases the server processing will have stopped before a response is received by the client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. All of your answers are very clear

Comment: Not only status codes with 200 are considered ok, but everything between [200, 299] and 304.
please refer to the source code of done() method in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8039410/4762075